# What is the fastest way to stack numpy arrays in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code that generates me within a `for` loop two numpy arrays (`data_transform`). In the first loop generates a numpy array of `(40, 2)` and in the second loop one of `(175, 2)`. I want to concatenate these two arrays into one, to give me an array of `(215, 2)`. I tried with `np.concatenate` and with `np.append`, but it gives me an error since the arrays must be the same size. Here is an example of how I am doing the code:

```
result_arr = np.array([])

for label in labels_set:
    data = [index for index, value in enumerate(labels_list) if value == label]
    for i in data:
        sub_corpus.append(corpus[i])
    data_sub_tfidf = vec.fit_transform(sub_corpus) 
    data_transform = pca.fit_transform(data_sub_tfidf) 
    #Append array
    sub_corpus = []
```

I have also used `np.row_stack` but nothing else gives me a value of `(175, 2)` which is the second array I want to concatenate.

Comment: You assign `result_arr` at the start. Why?  Then in the loop you assign it again - but don't use it as an argument for `row_stack`.   Are you trying to imitate a list `append` loop?

Comment: @hpaulj I try to create an empty array to fill it. I just want to do the operation that I do when I append values to a `list`.

Comment: Stick with the list append; don't try to imitate it with arrays.  Make the array in one step, at the end.

Comment: `alist.append(x)` operates in-place on `alist`.  `np.row_stack(data_transform)` returns a new array.  It doesn't not use or operate on `result_arr`, which does not appear at all in that expression.  The `result_arr=...` step just replaces the previous value with a new one.  The syntax is totally different from the list code.

Comment: @hpaulj I know but I want to perform the operation that `alist.append()` does, but with a `numpy`.

Comment: List append adds a pointer/reference to itself.  There's isn't anything equivalent for arrays.  To join two arrays you have to make a new one.  That's more expensive than the simpler list append.  And you have to pay close attention to the shape of the respective arrays - `concatenate` (and the stack variants) is quite picky about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What @hpaulj was trying to say with

> Stick with list append when doing loops.

is

```
#use a normal list
result_arr = []

for label in labels_set:

    data_transform = pca.fit_transform(data_sub_tfidf) 

    # append the data_transform object to that list
    # Note: this is not np.append(), which is slow here
    result_arr.append(data_transform)

# and stack it after the loop
# This prevents slow memory allocation in the loop. 
# So only one large chunk of memory is allocated since
# the final size of the concatenated array is known.

result_arr = np.concatenate(result_arr)

# or 
result_arr = np.stack(result_arr, axis=0)

# or
result_arr = np.vstack(result_arr)
```

Your arrays don't really have different dimensions. They have one different dimension, the other one is identical. And in that case you can always stack along the "different" dimension.

Comment: Is there actually a difference between `np.concatenate` and `np.stack` here? concatenate seems to row them column-wise into the matrix, while stack seems to stack them row-wise on top of eachother..

Comment: What if you want to vertically concatenate multiple 2D arrays in a for loop without using np.vstack()?

Comment: How do you make sure it is not np append?

Answer (score 1):

Using concatenate, initializing "c":

```
a = np.array([[8,3,1],[2,5,1],[6,5,2]])
b = np.array([[2,5,1],[2,5,2]])
matrix = [a,b]

c = np.empty([0,matrix[0].shape[1]])

for v in matrix:
    c = np.append(c, v, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
[[8. 3. 1.]
 [2. 5. 1.]
 [6. 5. 2.]
 [2. 5. 1.]
 [2. 5. 2.]]
```

Comment: Repeated `concatenate` is slow.  Stick with list append when doing loops.

Comment: I turned your comment into an answer, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Manuel, `np.append()` and `np.concatenate()` are both slow when used in a for loop, they basically do the same thing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array `a` of size `(40, 2)` and an array `b` of size `(175,2)`, you can simply have a final array of size `(215, 2)` using `np.concatenate([a,b])`.

Comment: I know. The problem is that I don't have two arrays, only one. The variable `data_transform` change in every loop.