# OpenCV merge contour

Tags: python, opencv

I have varying number of contours that I want to merge after cv.findContours(). Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501723/how-to-merge-contours-in-opencv), np.vstack seems to be the best way. But, the example given stack two specific contours 5 and 6. The contour number varies in my case. So, sort them in size, then loop through the desired ones is one way I could think of.

```
# For example:

data_contours = cv.findContours(img, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
data_cnt = sorted(data_contours, key=len, reverse=True)

# Find contour sizes
data_cnt_len = [len(data_cnt[i]) for i in range(len(data_cnt))]

print(f"Total number of contours: {len(data_contours)}")
print(f"Contour size: {data_cnt_len}")

# Total number of contours: 7
# Contour size: [5754, 407, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now, in a for loop, I want to merge the two largest contour (i.e., 5754 and 407). My current code using np.vstack only gives the last contour shape. How do I get these two contours merged? It should be (5754+407)=6161 or (6161,2). Thank you!

```
# Current code

contour_number = 2  # The first two contours

for i in range(contour_number):  
    
    # Stack contours
    contours = np.vstack(data_cnt[i])

print(contours.shape)
#(407,2)
```

Comment: Use the second method in link you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I came across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083743/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-stack-numpy-arrays-in-a-loop) and found the solution. Basically, append in list while looping is the key. I'll leave my updated code here, hopefully to help anyone runs into similar problem ;)

```
# Updated code

contours = []       # Create a list
contour_number = 2  # The first two contours

for i in range(contour_number):  
    contours.append(data_cnt[i])

contours = np.vstack(contours)

print(contours.shape)
#(6161,2)
```